# MongoDB & PHP | How to add object into existing document?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am very new to MongoDB and PHP and I am trying to add an object into an already existing document.
The problem is that I am seeing the `$push` variable being used a lot, but can't seem to get it working on my own project.

**My Document**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "622dfd21f8976876e162c303"
    },
    "name": "testuser",
    "password": "1234"
}
```

Lets say this is a document inside my collection `users`. I want to add an object that is called `domains` with some data inside that object like below:

```
"domains": {
        "name": "example.com"
}
```

I have tried a bunch of different things, but they do not seem to work.
**What I tried:**
I have tried doing to like this:

```
$doc = array(
    "domains" => array("name": "nu.nl")
);

$collection->insert($doc);
```

And like this:

```
$insertOneResult = $collection->updateOne(
    {"name" : "testuser"},
    '$push': {"domains": {"name": "example.com"}}
);
```

But they both do not work.
Can anyone help me with this problem or comment a link which would help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close!

```js
db.users.update({
  "name": "testuser"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "domains": {
      "name": "example.com"
    }
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p5CWiRe9P4n).

I haven't used `php` since the ancient `gforge` days, but my guess at using the `php` connector would be (corrections welcome!):

```php
<?php

$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->test->users;

$updateResult = $collection->updateOne(
    ['name' => 'testuser'],
    ['$push' => ['domains' => ['name' => 'example.com']]]
);

printf("Matched %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getMatchedCount());
printf("Modified %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getModifiedCount());
```

Comment: How would that look in PHP, since I need to do it in that language?

Comment: @Coder  See answer update for my **guess** at `php`.

Comment: I have one more question. What if I want to add an object within the domain object now (so adding an object within an object that is in a document), how would I do that? I cannot seem to figure it out

Comment: @Coder Probably best to ask a new question showing the doc before/after with what you've tried.

Comment: Did it! Thanks for the tip!